# Recursive sine sequence and non recursive expression

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let $(a_n)$ be the sequence defined as $$a_{n} = \begin{cases}\sin(a_{n-1})&\text{if $n>0$}\\k &\text{if $n=0$}\end{cases}$$
>   where $k\in[0,2\pi)$. Prove that
>
> 1. $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n = 0$
> 2. Exists $b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(\sin(a_n)^b-a_n^b)\neq0$
> 3. Find an alternative form for $(a_n)$

I already prove that the sequence converges to $0$. And that if $b$ exists it must be negative, but I can't arrange to see that it must exists. Any idea to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

The Taylor series for $\sin x$ is $x-x^3/6+...$.
So $(\sin x)^b-x^b\approx x^b(1-x^2/6)^b-x^b$.
Choose a value of $b$ so the leading term is $O(x^0)=O(1)$.

Comment: but if the leading term is $O(1)$, then all can be the same constant and go to $0$. Or am I wrong?